# Entity Framework: Error on Insert

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

I'm having trouble trying *insert* using EF.  Here's the situation:

1. I made a normal insert when I created a new registry where a PK received a return of `MAX` function from SQL
2. Then I've deleted this row from database without EF
3. Finally, I've tried to insert a new registry with EF, like I did on step 1

I then get this message from Visual Studio:

> The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values are unique before calling AcceptChanges

To illustrate my problem, I made [this small video](http://screencast.com/t/AXvuqlOmte).

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: If you stop your program between step 2 and 3 and restart it, what happens?

Comment: In this case, works just fine

Comment: Entity Framework keeps a copy of the entities in memory when you load them. So if the entities are already loaded and you delete a row in the database, there is still a copy in memory. Now when you try to insert an entity, EF sees that there is already an existing object with the same key in memory (even though it's already deleted in the db), and throws an error.

Comment: That's why I asked about stopping and starting it between steps 2 and 3 - wanted to test that theory

Comment: This is exactly my problem @OJRaqueño. 
I'm worked all day yesterday and still didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `AsNoTracking` when you originally retrieve the entities:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var myEntities = context.MyEntities.AsNoTracking();

    // then you can manually delete a row in the database
    // and insert it again here in code

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This way, the entities will not be cached by the `ObjectContext`. Note that this will impact areas of your code that depend on the tracking mechanism, if any.

Comment: Thanks for the Help @OJRaqueño.


I've tried your solution all day long, with severals ways, but none of them worked.


Then I continued looking for answers until I find this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f57428a8-1430-4e06-be32-70ddc3f27f84/key-clash-when-adding-deleting-and-readding-entity-with-same-key-why?forum=adodotnetentityframework).


I'm starting to think this problem has no solution besides refactor all my database. But this solution is realy costly.


Do you have any other idea that I can try it?